# Превьюшка(зум) от ImageView Android

Tags: android, zoom, android-imageview, preview

Всем привет. Я бы хотел узнать(***наглядный примерчик***),как можно сделать превьюшку области ImageView(наглядный пример это приложение **CamScanner**).

На текущий момент реализовано следующее: имеется 4 точки(imageView),которые соединены линиями. Эти точки,можно передвигать по определенной области(т.е. пользователь может передвигать "точку" в любом направлении).

И наконец,то что мне нужно конкретно (опять посредством **CamScanner**"а):
Исходное **изображение**
[image: SourceImg]

И после того,как юзер нажал на "точку" и начал передвигать,то отображается определенная область в кружке,который расположен сверху(область,которая соответствует зажатой точке).

[image: Action]

В общем нужна ваша помощь или годный туториал. Есть идеи,как достичь этого прекрасного инструмента?
Благодарю!

Comment: Ну... У вас есть координаты нажатия и размеры картинки. Засим вам надо получить BitMap картинки и пиксели вокруг координат. Их поместить в кружок. Как в коде - не напишу. На яве такого не делал.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ну что то вроде,а на чем делал? )

Comment: ActionScript3...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ясненько. Я такого не делал и не совсем понятно,как брать "область",относительно координат...что то ничего не приходит на ум)

Comment: Да всё просто - получите координаты пикселя в `BitMap` по координатам в `ImageView` и берите **n** пикселей слева/справа/сверху/снизу. Наверняка есть методы для взятия области вокруг пикселя.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб пиксели я могу взять,а вот обрисовка их(границы),надо будет загуглить. Спасибо за идею)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение оказалось достаточно **не простым**(в моем случае),хотя сама концепция тривиальная.

Вдохновился [этим](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442934/magnifying-part-of-the-canvas-when-touched) и [этим](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32055525/how-to-magnify-zoom-part-of-image)!

И запилил свой [**ЗУМ**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/471953/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-drawbitmapcanvas).