# Как отрисовать часть Битмапа посредством метода DrawBitmap(Canvas)

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, border, drawbitmap

Всем привет,имеется следующее:
 [image: source condition]:

1. FrameLayout(отображен красным цветом)
2. Исходный ImageView(черный)
3. Квадричный объект(imageview) с прикрученным OnTouchListener'ом (оранжевый),он создан внутри FrameLayout'a.

Посредством **Объекта** с OnTouchListener"ом,я хочу показывать "**часть**" Битмапа,который установлен в исходный ImageView.

В общем я делаю что то подобное:
`Bitmap bt = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap,event.getX(),event.getY(),250,250);`

**где**:

1. **SourceBitmap** - изображение,которые установлено в исходный ImageView
2. **event.getX()** / **event.getY()**  координаты(квадричного объекта),с которого я начинаю рисовать "**часть**" Битмапа.
3. **250**,**250** - размеры "кусочка" Битмапа.

и полученный результат :

[image: result of first case]

В общем проблема появляется,когда объект(с прикрученным OnTouchListener'ом),переходит за границу **исходного** ImageView(имеется такая возможность,т.е. половина длины,может уйти за границу).

Т.е. в этом случае :
[image: case #2]
я ожидаю этот результат:
[image: excepted result of case #2]
конкретнее :

1. Часть битмапа.
2. Вторая часть,это "**пустота**",то бишь цвет Framelayout(background).

Что я пытался на текущий момент:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            //я хочу получить большую порцию,чем текущие координаты
            int CurrentX = (int)view.getX() - (view.getWidth());
            int CurrentY = (int)view.getY() - (view.getHeight());

            //случай когда изображение ушло за границы
            if(CurrentX <= 0)
            {
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setStyle( Style.FILL  );
                paint.setColor( Color.RED );

                mBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(sourceBitmap,(int)view.getX() + Math.abs(CurrentX),(int)view.getY(),250,250);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
                canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap,new Rect((int)view.getX()+Math.abs(CurrentX), (int)view.getY(),250-Math.abs(CurrentX),250),new RectF(Math.abs(CurrentX), 0, 250,250),paint);
            }
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
}
```

И проблема заключается в том,что результат не тот,который я ожидаю.
А так же,как можно получить "результат"(прямоугольник),без исходного изображения,т.к. из за **canvas.drawBitmap** результат рисуется поверх оригинального изображения.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В моем случае, а именно,когда объект с прикрученным `OnTouchListener`, который может уходить за границы X,Y осей,относительно исходного `ImageView`,я сделал специальные правила(пост условия).

Условия:

Width = Ширина `ImageView`,в котором я буду показывать результат.
Height = Высота `ImageView`,в котором я буду показывать результат.

Левая cторона:

1. `X_Coord < 0  && Y_Coord - Height / 2 < 0 && Y_Coord < Bitmap.Height`  - это будет верхняя часть.
2. `X_Coord < 0  && Y_Coord - Height / 2 > 0 && Y_Coord < Bitmap.Height` - это будет средняя часть.
3. `X_Coord < 0  && Y_Coord - Height / 2 > 0 && Y_Coord > Bitmap.Height` - это будет нижняя часть.

Правая сторона:

1. `X_Coord > Bitmap.Height  && Y_Coord - Height / 2 > 0 && Y_Coord < Bitmap.Height`  - это будет средняя часть.
2. `X_Coord > Bitmap.Height  && Y_Coord - Height / 2 < 0 && Y_Coord < Bitmap.Height`  - это будет верхняя часть.
3. `X_Coord > Bitmap.Height  && Y_Coord - Height / 2 > 0 && Y_Coord > Bitmap.Height` - это будет нижняя часть.

Стандарт(средняя часть,которая не доходит краев(правой \ левой стороны) исходного `ImageView`):

1. `X_Coord - Width / 2 > 0 && X_Coord < Bitmap.Width   && Y_Coord - Height / 2 < 0 && Y_Coord < Bitmap.Height`   - это будет верхняя часть.
2. `X_Coord - Width / 2 > 0 && X_Coord < Bitmap.Width   && Y_Coord - Height / 2 > 0 && Y_Coord > Bitmap.Height` -  это будет нижняя часть.
3. `X_Coord - Width / 2 > 0 && X_Coord < Bitmap.Width   && Y_Coord - Height / 2 > 0 && Y_Coord < Bitmap.Height`  - это будет средняя часть.

Посредством этих "Пост условий", я буду отрисовывать кусочек(порцию) Битмапа в случае `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`.

Давайте рассмотрим пример:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        int Width = ResultImgView.getWidth();
        int Height = ResultImgView.getHeight();
        //paint для красного бэкграунда
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle( Style.FILL  );
        paint.setColor( Color.RED );
        Bitmap mBitmap = null;
        Canvas canvas = null;

        //Наше условие
        if(view.getX() - Width / 2 >= SourceBitmap.getWidth() 
            && view.getY() - Height / 2 > 0 && view.getY() + Height / 2 <  SourceBitmap.getHeight())
        {
            //Отлично! Мы зашли сюда,а это значит,что в данный момент времени, мы находимся в **Правой Стороне** и относимся к "Средней" Площади.
            //Теперь можно начать рисовать порцию битмапа.
            //Считаем наш отступ по Х 
            int Difference = (int)((view.getX() - Width / 2 ) - SourceBitmap.getWidth();
            //не забываем установить этот "отступ"
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(SourceBitmap, ((int)view.getX() - Width / 2) - Difference, (int)view.getY() - Height / 2, Width,Height);
            canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
            //рисуем наш бэкграунд в виде прямоугольника
            canvas.drawRect(0,0,mBitmap.Width,mBitmap.getHeight(),paint);
            //рисуем порцию битмапа
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap,new Rect(Difference, 0,mBitmap.getWidth(),mBitmap.getHeight()),new Rect(0,0,mBitmap.getWidth() - Difference,mBitmap.getHeight()),null);
            //на этом всем!
        }

        //проделать такого же плана работу и для других условий.
        break;
}



   return true;
}
```

Comment: Все очень рады, что вы сделали что то сами, но политика данного ресурса [вовсе не одобряет](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/93/177345) подобные "откровения", а так же неуместное количество восклицательных знаков, жирных шрифтов и проч. несущественного к решению вопроса.